# Ifelse() R using transmute_at(), multiple columns, same condition, different return value

Tags: if-statement, dplyr

I am wondering how I can automate the replacement of values in boolean columns (the values are 0 and 1) using transmute_at(). The replacement value depends on the column, but the condition is the same: if the value is 1, then it shall be replaced by a string value (which in this example should be a fruit name. For the real example I have a vector of strings similar to the strings of fruit names here).

Here is the dataframe. The columns were supposed to be different from each other, but I didn't know how to sample differently per column:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=5,ncol=4,data=sample(0:1, 10, replace = T)))
```

Here is the fruit names. replacement[1] should replace all 1's for column X1, and replacement[2] replacing 1's in column X2, and so forth:

```
replacement <- sample(fruit,4)
```

I have tried to work out this line using dplyr in R. The real dataframe have more columns, so I do need to select the columns during mutation:

```
     df %>% 
  transmute_at(vars(matches("X")), ~ifelse(. == 1, replacement, .))
```

I might have an idea that R doesn't understand which value to replace the 1's with when I'm feeding it a whole vector of values, though I don't know exactly how to specify it.

Comment: `object 'fruit' not found`

Comment: `transmute_at` has been superseded by `across`.

Comment: I'm inferring `fruit` is a `character` vector, in which case there is something a little broken: `replacement` is `character`, but the original data is `integer`. When you `ifelse(..)` those, you are likely to get all-`character`, but it is feasible (if there are no 1s) that you will get `integer` returned, this is one of `ifelse`'s flaws. If you intend for it to always be string (e.g., "apple" or "0"), then at least for declarative purposes use `ifelse(.., replacement, as.character(.))`, and then consider using `dplyr::if_else`, it is generally much safer.

Comment: I am fine with the final/replaced columns being `character`. I am sorry, I thought the `fruit` vector was available in R. I am not sure I understand how I can use `if_else()` to replace all of the columns using `transmute(across(....))`?

Answer (score 0):

Two notes:

1. `transmute_at` has been superseded by `across`. If we didn't have per-column varying `replacement`, then this would be enough ... but we need to be a little more creative. I suggest a simple "lookup" based on the column name.
2. Because you are mixing classes (`replacement` is `character` but your columns are `integer`), `ifelse` *may* produce inconsistent results: if anything is replaced with the fruit, then the column will be `character`, but if nothing is replaced then the column will remain `integer`. The fix is to use `as.character(.)`.

   One problem is that if you don't do this, you won't know about the risk until something downstream complains because your column is not `character` as you expect. The use of `dplyr::if_else` (if already using `dplyr`) or `data.table::fifelse` (analogous, just fyi here) mandates that you be clearer about this, making sure that you do not put yourself in this risky position.
3. You define `replacement` as a vector of length 4, which I'm inferring is meant to align with the columns of the frame. However, since you use `matches("X")`, there is the potential (*defensive programming*) that you try to run this on a frame with a different number of columns. Even if you don't ... it's bad practice hard-coding **magic constants** in your code, I suggest you define `replacement` based on the number of matching columns.

```r
set.seed(42)
replacement <- sample(stringr::fruit, sum(grepl("X", names(df))))
names(replacement) <- grep("X", names(df), value = TRUE)
replacement
#        X1        X2        X3        X4 
#   "mango"  "pomelo"    "date" "satsuma" 

df %>%
  transmute(across(
    matches("X"), ~ if_else(. == 1, replacement[cur_column()], as.character(.))
  ))
#      X1     X2   X3      X4
# 1     0 pomelo    0 satsuma
# 2     0      0    0       0
# 3 mango      0 date       0
# 4 mango      0 date       0
# 5     0 pomelo    0 satsuma
```

Comment: I just tested twice, and it worked! Thank you for your help!